# Google drive getMimeType returning only null values

Tags: java, null, google-drive-api, mime-types

I am trying to download files from drive using version 3 of Google Drive api in java. I now need the MimeType of files to identify their content type.
when I tried calling

> File.getMimeType

i am getting null value.

```
 Drive service=getDriveService();

 FileList result = service.files().list()    
          .setPageSize(100)
           .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
             .execute();


 List<File> files = result.getFiles();
     if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
         System.out.println("No files found.");
     }
     else {
         System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)(%s)\n", file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getMimeType());
            }
      }
```

I tried calling other methods like getFullFileExtension but they all are returning null values.

Could anyone please tell me where i did mistake?
And how to solve this get the mimetype and other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't played much with v3 yet, but from your code you do

```
setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
```

and then

```
file.getMimeType()
```

Since you only asked for the id and name to be fetched, it shouldn't be too surprising that mimeType is null. Try adding `mimeType` to the fields in `setFields`.